# Change logic for admin views in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am creating a website in pure django where I have the following model.

```
class GoodsDetails(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    goods_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gross_weight = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.serial_number}"
```

I have registered the model in the administration and I want to show all the model instances to the superuser but to non-superusers, I want to show only those instances where `is_active = False`. How can this be achieved in django administration?

I researched about it and think that I should create a custom permission for this job. However, I think that modifying the admin views logic would be better because in this case, changing the ORM query a bit will get the job done. Any other approaches are also welcome.

Thank you for your suggestions and/or solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `admin.py` add

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import GoodsDetails

@admin.register(GoodsDetails)
class GoodsDetailsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'serial_number', 'goods_description', 'quantity', 'gross_weight', 'is_active')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            return qs.filter(is_active=False)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was thinking about :)